# como agregar un href todo lo que tenga en la tabla

Tags: href

tengo este codigo, que me crea la tabla y me trae todo, como hago que loque traiga se comvierta en en laces

```
function crearTabla(){
  var data = getData();

  var tabla = '<table border = "1">\n';

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

    tabla += '<tr">';
    for(var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++){
      tabla += '<td>' + data[i][j] + '</td>'
    }
    tabla += '</tr>\n';
  }
  tabla += '</table>';
  return tabla;
}
```

Comment: supongo que lo que necesitas es que cada celda que creas quede con un enlace a una pagina?

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer crear la etiqueta "a" dentro de las etiquetas "td" y asi esa celda quedaria como un enlace, asi

```
function crearTabla(){

var data = getData();

  var tabla = '<table border = "1">\n';

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

    tabla += '<tr">';
    for(var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++){
                    //aqui genera el enlace tambien puedes darte un type buton  o darle clases 
                    //de bootstrap para que se muestrecomo boton
          tabla += '<td><a href="aqui_tu_url_destino">' + data[i][j] + '</a></td>'
        }
        tabla += '</tr>\n';
      }
      tabla += '</table>';
      return tabla;
    }
```

Comment: es lo que estoy buscando, el codigo todo lo combierte en enlacens sin embargo, no abre la pagina que selecciono, en la parte del "aqui_tu_url_destino" puede ser x o y, ya que el for trae un tabla que esta en un hoja de calculo con datos x

Comment: Lo que quieres es que no importa en que parte de la table des "click" te dirija a una ruta en especial ?

Answer (score 0):

Si cada dato x que mencionas,  tiene una url especifica, te recomiendo que el dato x le asigne a otra variable, la url.

```js
function crearTabla(){

var data = getData();



  var tabla = '<table border = "1">\n';

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

    tabla += '<tr">';
    for(var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++){
                // la variable url dependiendo los datos cargados
                const datosX = data[i][j]; 
                const url;
                switch (datosX) {
                      case 1:
                        url='la respectiva url';
                        break;
                      case 2:
                        url='la respectiva url';
                        break;
                        //la cantidad de casos que se necesiten
                      }

                              
        tabla += '<td><a href="${url}">' + data[i][j] + '</a></td>'
        }
        tabla += '</tr>\n';
      }
      tabla += '</table>';
      return tabla;
    }
```

El código tiene la base que proporcionaste, los cambios que te han sugerido, y mi parte.

Los que supongo es que los 'dato[i][j]' son pocos y tienen cada uno Url.

el Switch asigna la url dependiendo del 'dato[i][j], que reciba.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] . Deberías documentar mejor tu código  y explicarlo paso a paso.   lectura obligatoria [answer]  un saludo